# How to make cursor jump to specific location in Android Studio live template?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, live-templates

I'm trying to modify the **AndroidLog** live templates in Android Studio 2.2.

The default `logd` template expands to

```
android.util.Log.d(TAG, "$METHOD_NAME$: $content$");
```

But usually, when I am logging, I want to log the variable values and I want auto-completion to help me with it. So I modified this template to the following:

```
android.util.Log.d(TAG, "$METHOD_NAME$: $content$" + $content$);
```

However, when I expand this, the cursor still lands on the first occurrence of `$content$`. I want it to land on the second occurrence so Android Studio can suggest the variable name via auto completion!

For example, if I want to log the user's login time from an instance of `User`, the log statement would something like this

```
Log.d(TAG, "isSessionExpired: user.getLoginTime():" + user.getLoginTime());
```

So I want the cursor to be after the **plus** sign for auto completion to help me.

How can I achieve this with Live Templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see how `soutv` live template is defined, you want something similar for your logging:

[image: soutv]

Comment: I guess, $END$ would place the cursor at a specific position after 'jumping' through all variable positions first. What I am looking for is a way to place the cursor after the '+' character in the example `Log.d(TAG, "isSessionExpired: user.getLoginTime():" + user.getLoginTime());` so auto completion can help me type `user.getLoginTime()` at two places simultaneously in the template.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.